# Using AsynTask or AsynTaskLoader subclass with Context in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, synchronization

I need to use AsynTask or AsynTaskLoader, Everything is going fine but when i am try to using Context in this sub class, The Leak memory problem is occur, please how can i solve this problem?

```
this is my code:
class GeoTask(var context: Context, var latitude:Double, var longitude:Double ):AsyncTask<Util, Util, Unit>() {

override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Util?) {
    val geocoder = Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault())
    val addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1)
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size > 0 && Geocoder.isPresent()) {
        LocationUtil.country_name = addresses[0].countryName
        LocationUtil.city_name = addresses[0].locality
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Without code it is hard to tell what causes the leak in your project.

Comment: this code for example:
class Geo(var context: Context) : AsynTask<Unit, Unit, Unit>(){
.........
}

Comment: I mean you should edit the question and add your relevant code unto it, do not use the comment cuz it is hard to read :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using `WeakReference`.

See [WeakReference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html)

**For example**

```
internal class GeoTask(var context: WeakReference<Context> .... {

    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?) {
        val geocoder = Geocoder(context.get(), Locale.getDefault())
      ....
    }
```

This is what I tried:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Test(WeakReference<Context>(this@MainActivity)).call()
    }

    class Test(val weakReference: WeakReference<Context>)
    {
        fun call()
        {
            Toast.makeText(weakReference.get(), "WeakReference Demo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but when i call it in Activity i must compensated (context) with (this) or (Applicationcontext) or (this@ActivityName) and that not possible when i use (WeakReference) ?

Comment: @user4399890 I've tried and its working... Check my updated answer.

Comment: the same problem: it is exit in run time and give me this error:( Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare())

Comment: If you are updating the UI or showing Toast message in `doInBackground`(i.e. in other thread), you'll get this error.

Comment: Using weak reference in an Asynctask is a hack, use a SingleLiveData in a ViewModel, or run the asynctask in a retained fragment and then use `getActivity()` in `onPostExecute()`